# What are the sizes for numbers in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I checked the [storage size](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size) but I'm confused when it comes to storing numbers.

1. In case of `Bytes`, what does "Byte length" mean? If I store `-128` what's the length? And in case of 12?
2. In case of Floating-point number and Integer, it doesn't matter if I store 325 or 9.9999999999999 it will always be 8 bytes?
3. In case of Array? Let' say we have ["ab", "bcd"], what's the size, `(2+3=5)` or `(2+1)+(3+1)=7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you store an array of bytes, the size will simply be the length of that array.  An array with a single byte value of -128 is still just one byte.
2. Yes, all numbers occupy the same 8-byte size, even if you don't see a fractional part.
3. The documentation says it's the sum of the array element sizes, so I would expect 7, the sum of the two individual string sizes, each encoded in UTF-8 + 1

Comment: Thank you again for helping me. At 1. I was referring to the third element in the list in the docs (Bytes -> Byte length) and not to an array of bytes. What is the length of that? I saw [Bytes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) is used as data type. And in case of array elements, it's always (the element size + 1), right?

Comment: -128 is a number, not a byte array.  So byte array rules don't apply.

Comment: I'm now more confused. Why would someone add the Bytes as a data type when there are numbers data type. So -128 is also a byte but is also a number. I am confused about that "Byte length".

Comment: If you're not writing byte arrays, then you don't need to worry about it. The reason why someone might want to store a byte array is if they have some small amount of binary data (e.g. an image, some file payload) that they want to associate with the document.  It's not very common, but it's documented and supported.

Comment: Perfectly understood. Thank you so much.